# Orchard CMS - Cannot access resources from Modules folder

Tags: iis-6, orchardcms

I installed Orchard on VPS with using IIS6, the installation was successful but, Orchard couldn't load .css in Modules folders (Error 404 - but it's ok in Themes). I don't know why and really confuse.

Could you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you check if there is a line like this in the styles folder under any module that doesn't work `<add name="StaticFile" path="*"` Try commenting it out?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this problem:
Because Orchard Modules was named with dot sign, but IIS6 URL Scan doesn't allow dot sign
.So we have to turn on this feature. I found here:

http://burgerminds.wordpress.com/tag/rejected-by-urlscan/

Comment: As it turns out, current versions of Orchard (2013) do not support IIS6